# If $F$ is a vector subspace of $E$ such that the interior is non empty, then $E=F$.

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

Let $(E,\|\cdot \|)$ a normed space and let $F$ a subspace of $E$. Prove that if the interior of $F$ is non empty, then $E=F$.

**Attempts**

Suppose $E$ has finite dimension. Suppose $\dim F<\dim E$. Let $E=Span\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ and suppose WLOG that $F=Span\{v_1,...,v_m\}$ with $m<n$. In particular, if $x=(x_1,...,x_m,0,...,0)\in F$, then for all $r$, $(x_1,...,x_m,\frac{r}{2},0,...,0)\notin F$ will always be in $B(x,r)$, and thus, there is no ball that is included in $F$. Therefore $Int(F)=\emptyset$.

**Question :** How can I do if $E$ has finite dimension ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $x$ be an interior point of $F$. Then there exists $r>0$ such that $B(x,r) \subset F$. In particular $x \in F$. Hence $||y|| <r$ implies $y+x \in B(x,r) \subset F$ so $y =(y+x)-x \in F$ because $F$ is a subspace. Now let $z$ be any non-zero element of $E$. Take $y=\frac r {2||z||} z$. Then $||y|| =\frac r 2<r$ so $y \in F$. Hence $z=\frac {2||z||} r y \in F$. Since $F$ is a subspace this implies $z \in F$. Thus $E=F$.

Answer (score 0):

An other way would be as following : let $a\in Int(F)$ and $x\in E$, $x\neq a$. Let $r>0$ s.t. for all $z\in E$, if $\|z-a\|<r$, then $z\in F$. Let $y$ s.t. $$y-a=\frac{r}{2\|x-a\|}(x-a).$$
In particular, $y\in F$. Moreover, $$x=a+\frac{2\|x-a\|}{r}(y-a),$$
and thus $x\in F$ as well. The claim follow.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with basis theory in infinite dimensions, but certainly I know that countable bases don't tend to play well with non-separable spaces.

Comment: @TheoBendit: At your opinion, the first point $\bullet$ is not correct ? (I also have doubt, but I wouldn't be surprised that it works).

Comment: Yes, I don't think the first point is right. Ignoring everything else, there's the issue of which basis are you using (Hamel, Schauder, Markushevic, etc). But, the common countable bases occur in separable spaces (notable exception: Hamel bases, which are always uncountable in infinite dimensional Banach spaces). So, a proof in this vein might be possible, but if you assume countable bases, it will only work in separable spaces.